# LGBM model: What could cause varying results with fixed seed?

Tags: python, lightgbm

I train a LightGBM model with the following Python code:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb

# Set parameters
params = {
    "objective": "regression",
    "num_leaves": 16,
    "learning_rate": 0.05,
    "feature_fraction": 0.5,
    "verbose": 0,
    "nthread": -1,
    "metric": "l1",
    "linear_tree": False,
    "bagging_fraction": 0.632,
    "bagging_freq": 1,
    "min_data_in_leaf": 20,
    "num_iterations": 200,
    "early_stopping_round": None,
    "seed": 42,
}

# Create datasets
df_train = lgb.Dataset(...)
df_test = lgb.Dataset(...)

# Train model
fit_lgb = lgb.train(
    params=params,
    train_set=df_train,
    valid_sets=[df_train, df_test]
)
```

Although I have a fixed seed (`seed=42`), I get varying results between runs. Where could these variations come from?

Edit:
Following the link from @Marjin, I extended/replaced the params with these:

```
"deterministic": True,
"nthread": 1,
"force_col_wise": True,
```

However, I still get varying results.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/3761

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? For example... what version of `lightgbm` are you using? what version of Python? You could, for example, use the datasets from `sklearn.datasets` (from `scikit-learn`).

With a reproducible example, and clarification of what precisely "varying results" means (different tree structure? different predictions on the same data? different feature importance?), you're more likely to get a specific and useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare ("diff") your model objects between runs - it will show if the changes affect your tree structure (eg. number of trees, leaves), or simply tree learned parameters (eg. leaf values.

Diffing is easy to accomplish, because LightGBM allows you to save booster objects in easily diffable text data format using the [`Booster.save_model(filename)`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.Booster.html#lightgbm.Booster.save_model) method.

Once you have and share this information, we can investigate further.